# Авторизация node+angular2

Tags: авторизация, angular2, логин

Доброго дня. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как нужно (или как лучше) сделать авторизацию на сайте. Сейчас у меня при логине через форму от webapi возвращается булевое значение (либо такой пользователь был найден в БД, либо нет) и если оно true, я добавляю cookie в браузер. И отдельно в app модуле у меня есть метод который по этому cookie делает запрос к БД и получает в ответ json строку с данными пользователя. 
Вопрос: как лучше сделать, так как у меня сейчас? Или чтобы информация о пользователе выдавалась сразу при логине через форму?

И как можно сделать глобальный объект (в моем случае данные о пользователе), чтобы к нему можно было обращаться из любого компонента?

Comment: еще не забываем про jwt, вот пища http://angularjs.blogspot.com.by/2016/11/easy-angular-authentication-with-json.html

Answer (score 0):

1) Лучше сделать второй вариант, когда данные при логировании приходят сразу без дополнительных запросов.

2.а) Сделайте сервис авторизации, в котором будут реализованы функции авторизации, обновления данных, выхода и т.д, а также данные об авторизованном пользователе, его разрешениях и т.д. Вы сможете инжектировать данный сервис в любое место и получать данные о пользователе.

2.б) Всё тоже самое, только данные о пользователе положите в сервис отвечающий за глобальные переменные.